# Sequence File of Objects into Hive

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hive, netcdf, sequencefile

We started with a bunch of data stored in NetCDF files. From there, some Java code was written to create sequence files from the NetCDF files. We don't know much about the original intentions of the code, but we have been able to learn a little bit about the sequence files themselves. Ultimately, we are trying to create tables within Hive using these sequence files, but seem incapable of doing so at the moment.

We know that the keys and values within the sequence files are stored as objects that implements WritableComparable. We are also capable of creating Java code to iterate through all of the data in the sequence files.

So, what would be necessary to actually get Hive to read the data within the objects of these sequence files properly?

Thanks in advanced!

**UPDATE:** The reason it is so difficult to describe where I am having trouble exactly is because I am not necessarily getting any errors. Hive is simply just reading the sequence files incorrectly. When running the Hadoop -text command on my sequence file I get a list of objects as such:

NetCDFCompositeKey@263c7e3f , NetCDFRecordWritable@4d846db5

The data is within those objects themselves. So, currently from the help of @Tariq I believe what I have to do in order to actually read those objects is to create a custom InputFormat to read the keys and a custom SerDe to serialize and deserialize the objects?

Comment: You are aware that Hive ignores keys in the sequence files and interprets the values as the table rows, right?

Comment: +1 for pointing that out @Olaf. Something to keep in mind while working with SequenceFiles through Hive.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that. And I have seen that I could possibly use a custom InputFormat as the user mentioned below. I'm not quite sure how to do that however. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, i'm not able to understand from your question where exactly you are facing the problem. If you wish to use SequenceFiles through Hive you just have to add STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE clause while issuing CREATE TABLE(most probably you already know this, nothing new). When you work on SequenceFiles Hive treats each key/value pair of the SequenceFiles similar to rows in normal files. Important thing here is that keys will be ignored. Apart from that nothing very special.

Having said that, if you wish to read both keys and values, you might have to write a custom InputFormat that can read both keys and values. See this [project](https://gist.github.com/dilip/2421795) for example. It allows us to access data stored in a SequenceFile's key.

Also, if your keys and values are custom classes, you will require to write a SerDe as well to serialize and deserialize your data.

HTH

P.S. : I don't know if this is exactly what you were looking for. Do let me know if it is not and add some more detail to your question. I'll try addressing that.

Comment: So, it seems like Hive is actually outputting the classes themselves. Similar to this: NetCDFRecordWritable@4d846db5

So, Yes I believe you did answer this in a way! I believe I am understanding this more and more now. So, I would create a custom InputFormat AND a custom SerDe! The InputFormat will read the data from my keys and the SerDe will actually read through the objects themselves?

Comment: So, it seems like I am confused on two things now. Is the SerDe serialization related to the Hadoop serialization? Or is the SerDe a serialization/deserialization just for Hive? Finally, I have to learn how to create custom versions! Any good sources?